# How to auto padding?

Tags: html, css

How to make like anchor, button auto padding fill entire parent available space? I think this problem already exist long time ago.

```css
body { margin: initial }

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  column-gap: 10px;
}

.grid > div {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: bisque;
}

.grid > div > a {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div><a href="">1</a></div>
  <div><a href="">2</a></div>
  <div><a href="">3</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean with auto-padding? To fill the entire parents space you could simpy, use `flexbox` and `flex-grow`

Comment: @tacoshy can u show the code? is it possible like anchor and button fill entire parent? i dont means the container like div. i know like div can fill other div. but anchor and button, different case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `flex-grow: 1` to the anchor to fill out the entire parents space. However this requires that the parent is declared as flexbox: `display: flex`

```css
.grid > div {
  display: flex;
}

.grid > div > a {
  flex-grow: 1;
}


/* original CSS */
body { margin: initial }

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  column-gap: 10px;
}

.grid > div {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: bisque;
}

.grid > div > a {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div><a href="">1</a></div>
  <div><a href="">2</a></div>
  <div><a href="">3</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, this that i want to achieve so when user click inside parent anchor active.

Comment: I still fail to see what this has to do with `auto-paddings`

Comment: u knows if no padding inside element, the target element will small surface to click. thats why with padding, it make the element have big surface to able click.

Comment: and with auto padding, it can easy to create a menu nav, just set the parent size (width, height), font-size. everything will auto.